# Returning A Float Array from a function

Tags: c++, function, return, typedef, pass-by-value

```
findwitholding(Gross_Pay,FDH_Witholding,FW_TAXRATE);
findwitholding(Gross_Pay,FDH_Witholding,SW_TAXRATE);
findwitholding(Gross_Pay,FDH_Witholding,HOSPITALIZATION);
```

How can I return the the values from all three functions called?

```
void findwitholding(farray Gross_Pay, farray FDH_Witholding,
                float Witholding)
{          
    for(int i = 0; i < ISIZE; i++)               
        FDH_Witholding[i] = Gross_Pay[i] * Witholding;     
}
```

How can I pass it by value? Like this?

```
typedef float farray[5] //we have to use typedef
farray FED,STATE,HOSPITAL;

 FED = findwitholding(Gross_Pay,FDH_Witholding,FW_TAXRATE);
 STATE = findwitholding(Gross_Pay,FDH_Witholding,SW_TAXRATE);
 HOSPITAL = findwitholding(Gross_Pay,FDH_Witholding,HOSPITALIZATION);
```

If so, should it be like this for the function?

```
*farray* findwitholding(farray Gross_Pay, farray FDH_Witholding,
                float Witholding)
    {          
        for(int i = 0; i < ISIZE; i++)               
            FDH_Witholding[i] = Gross_Pay[i] * Witholding;    
        return FDH_Witholding;
    }
```

Comment: C-style arrays don't play nice when used like that. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You could wrap the array in a struct, and return/pass instances of the struct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the size of the array is fixed use `std::array`:

```
using farray = std::array<float,ISIZE>;

farray findwitholding(const farray& gross_pay, float witholding){
  farray fdh_witholding;
  for(int i = 0; i != ISIZE; ++i)
    fdh_witholding[i] = gross_pay[i] * witholding;
  return fdh_witholding;
}

auto fed = findwitholding(gross_pay, FW_TAXRATE);
auto state = findwitholding(gross_pay, SW_TAXRATE);
auto hospital = findwitholding(gross_pay, HOSPITALIZATION);
```

If the size is dynamic, use `std::vector` similarly.