# How would I go on as to "return" string arrays between functions?

Tags: c++

Hey so I was experimenting what I knew and realized when I tried passing a string value with return it wasn't supported, any idea? Sorry if my code is noob style (I only have 2 months of experience), I was planning on splitting the code between functions but I can't seem to do it because returning my array of strings cant be done with return :( Here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int itemlist=0;


int c=0;
int r = 0;



int itemlistdec()
{
cout<<"How many items would you like to input?";
cin>>itemlist;  
return itemlist;
}


int main() {


itemlistdec();
string item[4][itemlist];//declares item and that columns equal to itemlist whose content is declared right above

    for (int c=0;c<itemlist;c++)
    {

        for (int r=0;r<3;r++) //DETERMINES WHERE EACH RECORD GOES
        {
        if (r==0)
        {

        cout<<"Please enter the name of the item ";
        }

        if (r==1)
        {
            cout<<"Please input the buying price\n";
        }

        if (r==2)
        {
            cout<<"Please input the selling price\n";
        }

            cin>>item[r][c];

        }
    }

    int calc[3][itemlist];//declaring calc and itemlist

    for (int r = 0;r<itemlist;r++)
    {
        istringstream(item[1][r])>>calc[0][r]; //TAKES BUYING PRICE INTO INT ARRAY FOR CALCULATION

    }

    for (int r = 0;r<itemlist;r++)
    {
        istringstream(item[2][r])>>calc[1][r]; //TAKES SELLING PRICE INTO INT ARRAY FOR CALCULATION

    }

    for (int fart = 0;fart<itemlist;fart++)
    {
        calc[2][fart] = calc[1][fart] - calc[0][fart]; //REPEATS CALCULATION FOR PROFIT UNTIL ITEMLIST IS REACHED
    }


    for (int r = 0;r<itemlist;r++)
    {

    stringstream ss;
    ss<<calc[2][r]; //CONVERTS BOTH PROFIT VALUES INTO STRINGS
    item[3][r] = ss.str();

    }


    cout<<"______________________________________________\n"; //DISPLAYS OUTPUT IN TABLE FORM
    cout<<"Item\t\tBuying Price\t\tSelling Price\t\tProfit\n";

        for (int c=0;c<itemlist;c++)
    {


        for (int r=0;r<4;r++)
        { 
            cout<<item[r][c]<<"\t\t";
            if (r==1)
            {
                cout<<"\t";
            }
            if (r==2)
            {
                cout<<"\t";
            }
            if (r==3)
            {
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn about the [containers in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), especially [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: To hammer in my previous comment, you should also learn that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) does not exist in C++, so a declaration like `string item[4][itemlist];` is technically invalid.

Comment: Err... But strangely my code runs smoothly in this state? Regardless, I will definitely read more, I'm majoring computer science and it's just my first coding course. :D Thank

Comment: Some compilers do support variable length arrays (VLAs) as extension of C++, but only because they choose to do so. You can´t rely that some C++ tool will accept VLAs. About the returning, it´s *possible* without vectors etc., but... use them if you have no reason not to. (and eg. vector has variable sizes guaranteed in C++)

Comment: @YourfavOreo You're using GCC? It got variable-length arrays as an extension to the language but it's non standard so should be avoided if you want portable code. Also many people don't like it due to how easy it is to get stackoverflows with them.

Comment: Take for example `std::array`, it is, in practice, just a normal array, but wrapped in an object that allows it to be passed around or returned from functions without much problem. Another tip, for while you feel uncomfortable with the standard containers, you could pass the array(s) as *arguments* instead, and modify the array inside the function as you please.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl It comes with Dev C++ and it's what my university told us to use and thanks will keep it in mind definitely. 

JoachimPileborg Interesting, I definitely need to practice more, 

What would you guys recommend for me to use then, I definitely don't want to make un-portable software

Comment: @deviantfan Thank you, will definitely keep it mind, I wonder why my lecturer taught us arrays but left vectors unmentioned anyway google is my friend

Comment: @YourfavOreo An alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c/27411483#27411483 You put the array in a copyable "envelope" (a struct).  You have to adjust the syntax a bit in your code, but you can use this for those dinosaur teachers who don't want you to use STL.

Comment: @YourfavOreo `It comes with Dev C++` Yes, that´s GCC (or MinGW on Windows, which basically is GCC for Windows, just with a different name). About your lecturer, the solutions without `std::vector` are more complicated and involve pointers, dynamic allocation (`new`) etc., and he/she probably want you to practice that ... but if it´s not explicitely prohibited...

Comment: WOAH, I was not expecting all this feedback... awesome community

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie aaaaand bookmarked.... thank you so much

Comment: @deviantfan yeah.... we definitely did not learn the other things you mentioned..... Can't wait for the advanced classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use vector, it's very  powerful. Like that:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > mySecondVector;
std::vector<std::string> myFirstVector;
myFirstVector.push_back("MyString");
mySecondVector.push_back(myFirstVector);
mySecondVector[i][j]; // to access
```

And for add, access to an element watch on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, I'll watch the link soon... Just currently occupied

Answer (score 0):

Returning an array is a bit goofy. you have to return it as a pointer, and as soon as you do that you lose all size information. You have this handled by itemlist hanging around as a global variable, but global variables impose their own set of limitations. For one, you can never have more than one of these arrays (unless they are all the same size) because multiple arrays would be storing their length in the same spot.

First you have to flip the orientation of the array to get the constant size on the right-most index. Frankly because of locality (all of the data with respect to one item is in the same memory region, so if you load one part of an item into cache you probably load all of it. This almost always results in a much faster program) it's probably better that way, anyway. Then you've probably noticed you can't just return `string[][]` or anything that looks like it without the compiler barking at you, so you have to play games defining custom data types that you can return.

```
typedef string (*arrayPtr)[4];
```

Now you could try

```
arrayPtr itemlistdec()
{
    cout << "How many items would you like to input?";
    cin >> itemlist;

    string item[itemlist][4]; 
    //load the array

    return item;
}
```

And itemlist knows how big the array is, but you get a new snag. Item goes out of scope on you and is no longer valid. Even more fun, `string item[itemlist][4];` isn't even legal C++ because `itemlist` isn't a constant value. It works as a convenience in some C++ compilers, but not all.

So how about this? Dynamic allocation of the array will make it outlive itemlistdec, but now you'll have to delete the array manually when you are done with it.

```
arrayPtr itemlistdec()
{
    cout << "How many items would you like to input?";
    cin >> itemlist;

    arrayPtr item = new string[itemlist][4]; 
    //load the array

    return item;
}
```

Now we've got something that works. We can make it a bit more readable (and less at the same time, because a reader has to track down just what an `array` is in order to know how to use it) by

```
typedef string (array)[4];    
typedef array (*arrayPtr);    

arrayPtr itemlistdec()
{
    cout << "How many items would you like to input?";
    cin >> itemlist;

    arrayPtr item = new array[itemlist]; 
    //load the array

    return item;
}
```

This does not extend to variable length on both dimensions or if you absolutely must have the constant on the inside index. For that case you need this bastich:

```
string ** itemlistdec()
{
    cout << "How many items would you like to input?";
    cin >> itemlist;
    string** item = new string*[4]; // 4 can be any number, but you also have to 
                                    // use it in place of 4 in the for loop
    for (size_t index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        item[index] = new string[itemlist];
    }
    //load the array

    return item;
}
```

Doable, but you now have picked up a bunch of memory management duties. All of the allocated memory must be released with `delete[]`. In the `string **` case, you have to run through the left-most index and `delete[]` all of the right-most arrays before deleting the left-most.

You can eliminate this with `vector<vector<string>>`, but in this case it's ugly. Great trick, but doesn't fit the overall program goal.

```
vector<vector<string>> itemlistdec()
{
    int itemlist;
    cout << "How many items would you like to input?";
    cin >> itemlist;
    vector<vector<string>> item(4, vector<string>(itemlist));
    for (int c=0;c<itemlist;c++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter the name of the item ";
        cin>>item[0][c];
        cout<<"Please input the buying price\n";
        cin>>item[1][c];
        cout<<"Please input the selling price\n";
        cin>>item[2][c];
    }

    return item;
}
```

Note I'm returning the local vector and counting on move semantics to move the vector on return rather than copying it. Also note that you don't need a global itemlist anymore because the vector knows how big it is. You can even add stuff to it later if you want. And also note I ditched the inner for loop on the input. It's not needed.

This works better than the array options, but I still don't like it. Item is calling out for its own class so we can take advantages of the goodies that object oriented programming brings. We can also the correct data types for all of the member variables. That way we can catch bad input as the user enters it and get rid of an extra integer array used by the calculation.

```
class Item
{
public:
    void read(istream & in)
    {
        // ignoring possibility of total failure of cin here.
        cout<<"Please enter the name of the item ";
        in >> name;
        cout<<"Please input the buying price\n";
        while (!(in >> buyPrice)) // loop until we read an integer from the user.
        {  
            in.clear();
            cout<<"Invalid. Please input the buying price\n";
        }
        cout<<"Please input the selling price\n";
        while (!(in >> sellPrice))
        {
            in.clear();
            cout<<"Invalid. Please input the selling price\n";
        }
        return in;
    }
    // calc logic method goes here.
    // output method goes here.
private:
    string name;
    int buyPrice;  // no screwing around with the calc array. numbers are 
                   //read in as numbers or the input fails
    int sellPrice;
};

vector<Item> itemlistdec()
{
    int nrItems = 0;
    cout << "How many items would you like to input?";
    cin >> nrItems;
    vector<Item> itemlist(nrItems);
    for (Item& item : itemlist)
    {
        item.read(cin);
    }

    return itemlist;
}
```

Note I'm not checking validity of all input, just that valid integers were used. Probably sufficient, but ehhhh.... I have accidentally closed stdin by mistake. Not a fun thing to debug. Anyway, you have worse problems if stdin is going down.

Comment: Your first two code examples don't compile, even if you used a constant array dimension. A 2-D array is NOT convertible to pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb your point is taken. I didn't follow the problem all the way through. I'm going to see what I can do to clarify the point I'm trying to make with those first two without tossing typdefs into the mix.

Comment: @MattMcNabb couldn't figure out how to do it without the typedefs, so I put them in. Changes the point I was trying to make by making a bad idea compile. Good learning experience, though.