# c++ . When to delete a C-style array to free memory

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I wrote a code to convert kilos to pounds and stone. A snippet is shown below.

```
float *weightoutput =  weight_conversion(weight);
```

with the function as below. I used a C-style array,

```
float* weight_conversion(float x){

float *stones_pounds = new float[2];  //C-style array 
float z, y;
z = x*0.15747304441776971; // (1 stone = 6.3503 kilo)
y = x*2.2026;              // (1 kilo = 2.2026 pounds)
stones_pounds[0] = z;
stones_pounds[1] = y;

return stones_pounds;
}
```

I have read in multiple posts that if you use "new", you have to use to "delete" to free up memory.The question I have is, how could I delete stones_pounds in this setup. Since stones_pounds is used till the last line within the function in return, i don't think i can use delete [] stones_pounds within the function. Since it is not a global variable, i cannot delete it within the main function as well. So how do I go about using the delete[] operator to free up memory? Is the only alternative changing the structure of the code to facilitate the delete[] operator?

Comment: why not use a `std::vector` or `std::array`? edit: in this case you could actually return a `std::pair<float, float>` which would probably be clearer

Comment: Please see [this question on returning arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c).  You can still use a C-style array in the return  and not need to use `new[]` at all (by using a `struct`).

Comment: Heck, why not just return a `struct`?

Comment: As a side point: what is `x`? what is `z`? what is `y`? These variable names give no meaning to the input or to the results. Unless you might need to have 10, 50, or even a 1000 values returned (i.e. if it is always only two values), a data structure with clear names (as well as a clear parameter name to the function) would make this code much clearer as to what it is doing.

Comment: @RyanP I agree. I was just experimenting with this option before I move to std::vector.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, Donnie..  I will try the struct option as well. I'm still figuring out the different options available. so one step at a time. 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array` is probably a better choice for what you want then using `new` or `delete` in this example.

With that said, you return the `new`-ed pointer and store the result as `float *weightoutput`. To free the memory, you should call `delete` on that when you're done with it via `delete [] weightoutput;`.

Comment: Agreed, std::array is a better choice. I will be replacing 'new' with std::array, but curiosity got the better of me. So I wanted to try this before I move on.