# C++ arduino library returning an array of ints with incorrect values

Tags: c++, arduino

I am currently writing a library for Arduino using C++ to take an 8 character hexadecimal RFID string from a reader and convert that string into bytes, treating every two characters as part of a single byte such that "1234ABCD" becomes 0X12, 0X34, 0XAB, 0XCD. These bytes are then converted into the integer values that represent them such that the previous values become 18, 52, 171 and 205 respectively. These integers will then be placed in an array and returned to the caller. As the RFID string is hexadecimal I am multiplying the integer value of the first character in each pair by 16.

The C++ library:

```
int AccessPortal::hexToInt(char character) {
  if(int(character) -  '0' < 10) {
    return int(character)  - '0';
  }
  else {
    if(isupper(character)) {
      return int(character) - '7';
    }
    else {
      return int(character) - 'W';
    }
  }
}

int* AccessPortal::getByteArray(std::string uid) {
  int byteArray[4];
  int intArray[8];
  int counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if(i  % 2 == 0) {
      intArray[i] = hexToInt(uid[i]) * 16;
    }
    else {
      intArray[i] = hexToInt(uid[i]);
    }
  }
  for(int i = 1; i < 8; i = i + 2) {
    byteArray[counter] = intArray[i - 1]  + intArray[i];
    counter ++;
  }
  return byteArray;
}
```

The Arduino code:

```
 void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      AccessPortal access(); //constructor 
      int *h;
      h = access.getByteArray("1234ABCD");
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Serial.println(h[i]);
      } 
    }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

    }
```

However, when I run the program the following is printed to serial:

```
1073741740
1073741680
1073670364
1075849820
```

This is strange because when I run the functions in the C++ library separately and print the results to the terminal the values are correct. I am guessing this means the error is occurring in the way the array is being returned and/or accessed in the Arduino code, however I am unsure.

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable. The life-time of local variables ends with the end of the function. Pointers to them will become invalid.

Comment: @OP This has nothing to do with Arduino.  It has everything to do with returning a pointer to a local variable leading to undefined behavior.  You can [return an array wrapped in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c/27411483#27411483).

Comment: Also, `AccessPortal access();` does not construct an object.  This declares a function that takes no arguments and returns an `AccessPortal`.

Comment: Allocate the array outside the function and let the function fill it as all low level C function do.

Comment: Using the `ByteArray` (I made below) that uses `strtoul` will probably be just as effective - and it can also be made global if pass-by-value is a worry. Pros: Small memory usage (max 8 bytes / ByteArray), strtoul is probably faster than the homecooked version. Cons: Uses a bitshift + an `and` gate to extract the 4 ints from the `uint32_t`.

Comment: It would help yourself *a lot* if you managed to remove the whole Arduino dependency from your code and instead provided a regular C++ [mcve]. If your code doesn't exhibit the same behaviour with a regular compiler and with Arduino, you would also gain some insights.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, a pointer to a local variable becomes invalid as soon as the local variable goes out of scope, so it shouldn't be returned. You can instead create a `ByteArray` object that you can return-by-value from your functions. Example using ArduinoSTL:

```
#include <ArduinoSTL.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

struct ByteArray {
    uint32_t m_value;
    bool m_valid;

    // convert hex string to uint32_t value
    ByteArray(const std::string& uid) :
        m_value(std::strtoul(uid.c_str(), nullptr, 16)),
        m_valid(true)
    {
        if(uid.size()!=8) m_valid = false;
    }

    // converting assignment operator
    ByteArray& operator=(const std::string& uid) {
        m_value = std::strtoul(uid.c_str(), nullptr, 16);
        if(uid.size()==8) m_valid = true;
        else m_valid = false;
        return *this;
    }

    // subscript operator to access the individual bytes (as ints)
    int operator[](size_t x) const {
        if(x>3) return -1;
        return (m_value>>((3-x)*8))&0xFF;
    }
};

struct AccessPortal {
    // change the getByteArray signature to this
    ByteArray getByteArray(const std::string&);
};

ByteArray AccessPortal::getByteArray(const std::string& uid) {
    // return by value - copy elision
    return ByteArray(uid);
}

void setup() {
    AccessPortal access; //default constructing
    ByteArray h = access.getByteArray("1234ABCD");

    Serial.println(h.m_value); // dec: 305441741  hex: 1234ABCD

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Serial.println(h[i]); // dec: 18, 52, 171, 205  hex: 12, 34, AB, CD
    }
}

void loop() {
    //
}
```

Comment: we are on an AVR microprocessor. no stdlib. array as parameter is the solution

Comment: You don't have the [Arduino STL](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/arduino-stl)? I'd install that to get more C++ into the project.

Comment: Tested it myself now but couldn't make `std::string` work (that you use) without ArduinoSTL so I changed the code back to using ArduinoSTL but removed the exception handling and added error handling possibilities instead.