# Object allocated on stack continues to exist after stack frame is gone

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ beginner, although I have some experience with C.  I was looking at this code snippet on operator overloading from this source:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Complex { 
private: 
    int real, imag; 
public: 
    Complex(int r = 0, int i =0)  {real = r;   imag = i;} 

    // This is automatically called when '+' is used with 
    // between two Complex objects 
    Complex operator + (Complex const &obj) { 
         Complex res; 
         res.real = real + obj.real; 
         res.imag = imag + obj.imag; 
         return res; 
    } 
    void print() { cout << real << " + i" << imag << endl; } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    Complex c1(10, 5), c2(2, 4); 
    Complex c3 = c1 + c2; // An example call to "operator+" 
    c3.print(); 
}
```

I do not understand how the "res" object created in the "+" function continues to exist after "+" returns.

Shouldn't the stack frame and all of its contents be deleted after the return statement?  My intuition says that c3 has been assigned to an object that no longer exists, so the call to c3's print function should not work, as the object it refers to has been destroyed.

If this was C, rather than C++, res could be saved by using "malloc" to allocate memory on the heap, meaning it wouldn't live in a stack frame and so would not be deleted.  But it seems that nothing of the sort is done here.

What is wrong with my reasoning?  Is this a difference between C and C++, or have I misremembered some aspect of C?  Or perhaps both?

Comment: It doesn't. `operator+` returns a copy of that object. Works the same way as in C.

Comment: *If this was C, rather than C+* -- You are wrong about `C`.  If you declare a `struct` in C and return it by value, there is absolutely nothing wrong with doing that.  So your entire reasoning is based on faulty logic.

Comment: For an example, [returning an array wrapped in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c/27411483#27411483).  This works in C and C++.

Comment: If you add a copy / move constructor in the `Complex` class you can see how the local object is being returned.

Comment: @Superman - except there is potential that the compiler will implement the return value optimisation and/or elide temporaries.   The C++ standards goes out of their way to permit that (all versions of the standard) or to require it in various circumstances (more recent versions of the standard).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the original res dies, but before that, res is copied into c3.  If I had instead returned a pointer to res, (and c3 was also a pointer rather than an object), the pointer would have been successfully copied, but the res object would have been destroyed, leaving c3 as a dangling pointer.  I think I ran into that problem in the past, and misremembered it as being the case here.  Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @Peter - yes, thanks for mentioning that. So make sure to run with all optimizations disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. `res` is copied into the return value, then `res` is destroyed, then the function returns.
Then the return value is copied into `c3`, then the return value is destroyed.