# Error encountered when trying to return a string array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner and I'm now learning all about arrays and experimenting different ways to implement it. This time, I really wanted to know how to return a string array in c++ without using vector for research purposes. I tried implementing pointers as a way to return a string array but it is giving me a runtime error stating that the string subscript is out of range. Kindly advice if I made the wrong way of returning the string array and provide better solutions for this.

**Here is the code the Employee.h:**

```
    #pragma once
    #include<string>
    #include<iostream>

    class Employee
    {
    private:
    static const int recordSize = 100;
    static const int fieldSize = 4;
    std::string record[recordSize][fieldSize];

    public:
    Employee();
    ~Employee();
    std::string * employeeReadData();

    };
```

Here is the Employee.cpp

```
 Employee::Employee()
 {
 }

std::string * Employee::employeeReadData() {
std::ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("C:\\Users\\RJ\\Desktop\\employee-info.txt");

static std::string recordCopy[recordSize][fieldSize];

for (int index = 0; index < recordSize; index++) {
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < fieldSize; index2++) {
        inFile >> record[index][index2];
    }
}

for (int index = 0; index < recordSize; index++) {
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < fieldSize; index2++) {
        recordCopy[index][index2] = record[index][index2];
    }
}

inFile.close();

std::string * point = * recordCopy;

return point;
    }
```

**Here is main():**

```
    int main()
    {
    Employee emp;


    std::string* p = emp.employeeReadData();

    cout << p[0][0] <<endl;
    cout << p[0][1] << endl;
    cout << p[0][2] << endl;
    cout << p[0][3] << endl;

    return 0;
   }
```

employee-info.txt:

```
    ID           Firstname            Lastname                 Sales
     1             Reynard             Drexler             150000.00
     2              Joseph               Bones             250000.00
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger? What line is is encountering it on exactly?

Comment: *I really wanted to know how to return a string array in c++ without using vector for research purposes.* -- You can't return arrays, unless you return a `std::array` or some class that wraps the array concept.   I guess that ends the research.

Comment: Also, I should mention that you are doing some weird things in your code, like returning point in `Employee::Employee()`. Also, declaring `static std::string recordCopy` might let you get away with returning the address (since it's static) but you might want to find a better way to do it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You can return a pointer, though--which can be treated like an array from the caller's point of view sometimes.

Comment: A pointer is not an array.  Trying to not have the OP believe they are doing something that isn't really being done.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Got you. Good point.

Comment: @Chipster *"like returning point in Employee::Employee()"* - look closer. `return point;` is in another member; not the constructor. The constructor is bone-empty.

Comment: @WhozCraig By George, you're right. I must have just missed the beginning of the new function. Still, the whole static thing is still slightly weird.

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c/27411483#27411483).

Comment: Consider using a structure instead of an array for the records. They are usually easier to wrangle.

Comment: What do you expect to print for `p[0][2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> provide better solutions for this.

Well, you can use the techniques shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c/27411483#27411483), and wrap the array into a struct within your `Employee` class.

```
#include <string>

class Employee
{
   public:
       struct EmployeeRecord
       {
           static const int recordSize = 100;
           static const int fieldSize = 4;
           std::string record[recordSize][fieldSize];
       };
    private:           
       EmployeeRecord emp_record;

    public:           
       Employee() {}
       ~Employee() {}
       EmployeeRecord& employeeReadData();
};
```

Then in the implementation:

```
 #include <fstream>

 Employee::Employee() {}

 Employee::EmployeeRecord& Employee::employeeReadData() 
 {
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\\Users\\RJ\\Desktop\\employee-info.txt");
    for (int index = 0; index < EmployeeRecord::recordSize; index++) 
    {
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < EmployeeRecord::fieldSize; index2++) 
            inFile >> emp_record.record[index][index2];
    }
    return emp_record;
}
```

Then:

```
int main()
{
    Employee emp;
    auto& p = emp.employeeReadData(); // return reference to the struct that has the array

    std::cout << p.record[0][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << p.record[0][1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << p.record[0][2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << p.record[0][3] << std::endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

There is no usage of pointers, and also no usage of vectors.  This is about as simple as you can get without usage of pointers.