# Sending data using TcpSocket in SFML causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sockets, sfml

I'm using SFML's `TcpSocket` class to send and receive data, but for some reason I keep getting the error `Segmentation fault: 11`. Here's the server class:

```
#include "ServerGame.hpp"

ServerGame::ServerGame()
{

}

void ServerGame::sendData(char data[3][3])
{

    if (client.send(data, 9) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        //std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }

}

void ServerGame::connect()
{
    sf::TcpListener listener;

    // bind the listener to a port
    if (listener.listen(666) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }

    // accept a new connection
    if (listener.accept(client) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
}

char** ServerGame::receiveData()
{
    char **data;
    data = new char*[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = new char[3];
    }
    std::size_t received;

    // TCP socket:
    if (client.receive(data, 9, received) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        // error...
    }
    return data;
}
```

Here's the client class:

```
#include "ClientGame.hpp"
#include <iostream>

ClientGame::ClientGame()
{

}

void ClientGame::connect()
{
    sf::Socket::Status status = socket.connect("127.0.0.1", 666);
    if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        // error...
    }
}

void ClientGame::sendData(char data[3][3])
{
    if(socket.send(data, 9) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        //error...
    }
}

char** ClientGame::receiveData()
{
    char **data;
    data = new char*[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = new char[3];
    }
    std::size_t received;
    if (socket.receive(data, 9, received) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
    return data;
}
```

This is the main class that starts the server and sends data:

```
#include "ServerGame.hpp"
#include "ClientGame.hpp"
int main()
{
    ServerGame sg;
    sg.connect();
    char arr[3][3] =
    {
        {'a', 'b', 'c'},
        {'d', 'e', 'f'},
        {'g', 'h', 'i'}
    };
    sg.sendData(arr);

}
```

This is the main class that starts the client and receives data:

```
#include "ClientGame.hpp"

int main()
{
    ClientGame cg;
    cg.connect();
    char** arr = cg.receiveData();
    std:: cout << arr[0][0] << std::endl;
}
```

I first compile and run the server class, and then do the same with the client class. When I try to access the first element of the character array I send, it gives a segmentation fault. Why is this happening?

Comment: `char **data;` -- A `char**` is **not** a two-dimensional array of `char`.  That is one huge mistake in your code, and that is assuming they are the same.

Comment: Drop all of that `char**` usage, and create a struct that has a simple `char[3][3]` in it.  In short, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c/27411483#27411483).  Make that internal array the array you can pass around using the struct wrapper.  I don't know if that's the only problem, but it **is** a problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is assuming that `char**` is the same as a two dimensional array of `char`.  They are **not** the same.

When you do this:

```
char **data;
data = new char*[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    data[i] = new char[3];
}
```

you are not creating a two-dimensional `char` array dynamically with a contiguous data layout, similar to a `char[3][3]`.  The memory layout could look something like this:

```
data[0] ->  0x32181000
data[1] ->  0x321A9760
data[2] ->  0x321AC980
```

In other words, the rows are strewn all over the heap memory, and are not contiguous.

Thus when you call this function:

```
if (socket.receive(data, 9, received) != sf::Socket::Done)
```

the `socket.receive` function is expecting a contiguous buffer of 9 bytes, but you are not providing this.  The `receive` function more than likely overwrites the first row with up to 6 bytes falling off the edge of the first row (the first row is allocated to only have 3 bytes), and thus spilling over into memory that causes the segmentation fault.

---

I think the issue stems from you trying to pass a two-dimensional array around from function to function, and making mistakes by using `char**` in lieu of an actual 2 dimensional array.

To make things easier without having to introduce pointers, create a `struct` that contains a 2-dimensional `char` array, and then pass this struct between the functions.

```
struct char2D
{
    char myArray[3][3];
};
```

Then instead of `char **`, just use an instance of `char2D`, and refer to the inner array when you need to.

For example:

```
char2D ClientGame::receiveData()
{
    char2D data;
    std::size_t received;
    if (socket.receive(&data.myArray[0][0], 9, received) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Then in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    ClientGame cg;
    cg.connect();
    char2D arr = cg.receiveData();
    std:: cout << arr.myArray[0][0] << std::endl;
}
```

The reason why this works is that a `struct` is copyable and assignable.  So the inner array gets copied whenever you pass it by value and return it by value.