# Returning arrays from functions (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function

My program is supposed to take the names and 5 marks each for 10 students and output their corresponding average marks and grade. My functions `avgmarks` and `avg_grade` are supposed to calculate and return these, as arrays, to the main function. Using the statements `return avg[10]` and `return gr[10]` does not work. I know pointer variables can be used here, but i don't know how to implement them to make my program work correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void readnames(string p[]);
int readmarks(int p[10][5]);
int avgmarks(int p[10][5]);
char avg_grade(int p[10]);
void displayresults(string n[], int m[], char g[]);
int main()
{
    string names[10];
    readnames(names);
    int marks [10][5];
    readmarks(marks);
    int avg_marks[10];
    avg_marks[10]=avgmarks(marks);
    char grade[10];
    grade[10]=avg_grade(avg_marks);
    displayresults(names, avg_marks, grade);
}
void readnames(string p[])
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student "<<i+1<<"'s name:\n";
        cin>>p[i];
    }
}
int readmarks(int p[10][5])
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student "<<i+1<<"'s marks:\n";
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            cin>>p[i][j];
        }
    }
}
int avgmarks(int p[10][5])
{
    int avg[10];
    int sum;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+p[i][j];
        }

        avg[i]=(sum/5);
    }

    return avg[10];
}
char avg_grade(int p[10])
{   
    char gr[10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if (p[i]>=90)
        {
            gr[i]='A';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=80)&&(p[i]<90))
        {
            gr[i]='B';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=70)&&(p[i]<80))
        {
            gr[i]='C';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=60)&&(p[i]<70))
        {
            gr[i]='D';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=50)&&(p[i]<60))
        {
            gr[i]='E';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=40)&&(p[i]<50))
        {
            gr[i]='F';
        } 
    }   
    return gr[10];
}
void displayresults(string n[], int m[], char g[])
{
    float ct;
    float sum=0;
    cout<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Name: "<<n[i]<<"    Average Marks: "<<m[i]<<"    Grade: "<<g[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+m[i];
    }
    ct=sum/10;
    cout<<"The class average is "<<ct<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Dont use c-style arrays, use std::array or std::vector

Comment: Why do you use "int" as a return type if you are trying to return an array?

Comment: `return avg[10];` -- Explain in your own words what this line is supposed to do.  Also [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c/27411483#27411483)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I meant for this line to return the array to return the array ```avg```

Comment: You don't return arrays from functions. You either pass in a pointer to an array for the function to fill, you return a suitably allocated array's pointer (C), or you return an `std::vector<>` (C++). This is a complete list. Deviate from it, and you will rue that decision.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be returned from functions. It's one good reason to use vectors instead of arrays (there are many more).

But if you want to carry on with arrays you should use pointers to simulate returning an array from your function.

In this example `avg` is a pointer to an array that will recieve the returned value

```
void avgmarks(int p[10][5], int* avg)
{
    int sum;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+p[i][j];
        }

        avg[i]=(sum/5);
    }
}
```

You use it like this

```
int avg_marks[10];
avgmarks(marks, avg_marks);
```

PS. You seem to have the common (but to me bizarre) newbie misunderstanding that if you have an array of size 10 (say) then `array[10]` can be used to refer to the whole array. Please don't think that, if you have an array of size 10, then `array[10]` is just an error, because the valid indexes for an array of size 10 are 0 to 9.

Comment: What do you mean you can't return an array from a function? See my answer, you absolutely can do that in C.

Comment: @FlatAssembler Well two issues. Firstly as you said yourself `make the function return the pointer.`, your function returns a pointer not an array. Secondly returning pointers to static objects is classic bad style.

Comment: Arrays ARE pointers in C. And why would having a pointer to a static object be a bad style?

Comment: @FlatAssembler because every access to the static object would change this object. It is no "new" array on its own, when you call the function

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, try `sizeof` on an array and on a pointer to see one example of the difference. Try writing `arr1 = arr2;` for another (works with pointers but not with arrays). As for the style issue, exactly as RoQuOTriX said.

Answer (score 0):

This example changed every c-style array to `std::array`. Keep in mind, that it is the same code as yours with the arrays, so every programming error is still in there. And also arrays are returned by value, means that they are copied. Try to understand how to use `std::array` and you will get a better programmer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void readnames(std::array<string, 10>& p);
void readmarks(std::array<std::array<int,5>, 10>& p);
std::array<int,10> avgmarks(std::array<std::array<int,5>, 10>& p);
std::array<char,10> avg_grade(std::array<int,10>& p);
void displayresults(std::array<string, 10> n, std::array<int,10> m, std::array<char,10> g);

int main()
{
    std::array<string, 10> names;
    readnames(names);
    std::array<std::array<int,5>, 10> marks;
    readmarks(marks);
    std::array<int,10> avg_marks;
    avg_marks = avgmarks(marks);
    std::array<char,10> grade;
    grade = avg_grade(avg_marks);
    displayresults(names, avg_marks, grade);
}

void readnames(std::array<string, 10>& p)
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student "<<i+1<<"'s name:\n";
        cin>>p[i];
    }
}

void readmarks(std::array<std::array<int,5>, 10>& p)
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student "<<i+1<<"'s marks:\n";
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            cin>>p[i][j];
        }
    }
}

std::array<int,10> avgmarks(std::array<std::array<int,5>, 10>& p)
{
    std::array<int,10> avg;
    int sum;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+p[i][j];
        }

        avg[i]=(sum/5);
    }

    return avg;
}

std::array<char,10> avg_grade(std::array<int,10>& p)
{   
    std::array<char,10> gr;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if (p[i]>=90)
        {
            gr[i]='A';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=80)&&(p[i]<90))
        {
            gr[i]='B';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=70)&&(p[i]<80))
        {
            gr[i]='C';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=60)&&(p[i]<70))
        {
            gr[i]='D';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=50)&&(p[i]<60))
        {
            gr[i]='E';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=40)&&(p[i]<50))
        {
            gr[i]='F';
        } 
    }   
    return gr;
}

void displayresults(std::array<string, 10> n, std::array<int,10> m, std::array<char,10> g)
{
    float ct;
    float sum=0;
    cout<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Name: "<<n[i]<<"    Average Marks: "<<m[i]<<"    Grade: "<<g[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+m[i];
    }
    ct=sum/10;
    cout<<"The class average is "<<ct<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void readnames(string p[]);
void readmarks(int p[10][5]);
int* avgmarks(int p[10][5]);
char* avg_grade(int p[10]);
void displayresults(string n[], int m[], char g[]);
int main()
{
    string names[10];
    readnames(names);
    int marks [10][5];
    readmarks(marks);
    int *avg_marks;
    avg_marks=avgmarks(marks);
    char *grade;
    grade=avg_grade(avg_marks);
    displayresults(names, avg_marks, grade);
}
void readnames(string p[])
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student "<<i+1<<"'s name:\n";
        cin>>p[i];
    }
}
void readmarks(int p[10][5])
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student "<<i+1<<"'s marks:\n";
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            cin>>p[i][j];
        }
    }
}
int* avgmarks(int p[10][5])
{
    static int avg[10];
    int sum;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+p[i][j];
        }

        avg[i]=(sum/5);
    }

    return avg;
}
char* avg_grade(int *p)
{   
    static char gr[10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if (p[i]>=90)
        {
            gr[i]='A';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=80)&&(p[i]<90))
        {
            gr[i]='B';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=70)&&(p[i]<80))
        {
            gr[i]='C';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=60)&&(p[i]<70))
        {
            gr[i]='D';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=50)&&(p[i]<60))
        {
            gr[i]='E';
        }
        if ((p[i]>=40)&&(p[i]<50))
        {
            gr[i]='F';
        } 
    }   
    return gr;
}
void displayresults(string n[], int m[], char g[])
{
    float ct;
    float sum=0;
    cout<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Name: "<<n[i]<<"    Average Marks: "<<m[i]<<"    Grade: "<<g[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+m[i];
    }
    ct=sum/10;
    cout<<"The class average is "<<ct<<endl;
}
```

Basically, to return an array from a function in C/C++, you declare it as "static", and you make the function return the pointer.

EDIT: As many others have noted, this won't work in multi-threaded programs.

Comment: Static has nothing to do with returning arrays.

Comment: Wow, then we all should only look that the code works, unaware of how bad it is

Comment: Which works fine until you get mysterious crashes in a threaded application...

Comment: This is a very kind request. I do not want to be rude or offensive. I deeply apologize for this. But maybe you could perhaps consider to delete your answer? It will give newbies the impression that you can return C-Style arrays from a function. I am sorry, but please kindly consider.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Well, that's true, but I don't think OP cares too much about that.

Comment: Do we need to put every new programmer through the pains of our past mistakes? Shouldn't we pass on the lessons we learned? `errno`, `rand()`, etc.? I don't care whether the OP cares about that now, I won't instruct them to use methodology that I know is deeply flawed.