# C++ Returning an Array using a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arguments

Doing a beginner coding assignment for my c++ course. I'm fairly new and pointers has me stumbling a bit. What I'm trying to do with my code is have the function intSwapper return an array using a pointer. Since arrays can't be normally returned, I have to use a pointer but I'm still trying to figure out how to make that work.

```
int* intSwapper(int* inputArray, int size) {
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     int* p = &inputArray[i];
     int* j = &size;
     //The static int I created below was just to test if I could even return what I needed.
     static int arr[size] = { 3,4,5,9,1 };
     int* p2 = arr;
     return arr;
     delete p;
     delete p2;
}
```

}

The code above does not even work, let me say that, that's just a combination of failing and testing different things. The thing I'm trying to achieve is to pass the size and array through the function, and the function intSwapper is supposed to change the first number of the array being passed in with the last. Then, the second number is supposed to match the second to last number being passed in. The return type should be a pointer I believe. The assignment isn't as easy as reversing the numbers and calling it quits. Apparently you don't dynamically create memory or create a new array for this so I'm really lost. Thanks in advance you all, hope I was able to provide enough information.

Comment: is VLA even a thing in CPP?

Comment: `static int arr[size] = { 3,4,5,9,1 };` -- This is not valid C++, as arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value like `size`.

Comment: *Since arrays can't be normally returned, I have to use a pointer* -- You don't have to use a pointer.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c/27411483#27411483)

Comment: Use `std::array` if you have a fixed size.  Else use `std::vector`.

Comment: `delete p;delete p2;` wait what? Are you using a good book or tutorial to learn C++ or just randomly trying stuff? What do you think `delete` does?

Comment: Can you delete anything after `return`?

Comment: Most likely your return statement should be as simple as this: `return  inputArray;`. However, the body of your function looks like The Texas Chain Saw Massacre and I have no idea what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the code you're looking for:

```
void intSwapper(int* inputArray, int size) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
        temp = inputArray[i];
        inputArray[i] = inputArray[size - 1 - i];
        inputArray[size - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}
```

So a pointer points to some address in the memory.
The array is some values with consecutive adresses in the memory.
The array is represented by the pointer to the first element.
inputArray is the pointer. inputArray[0] gives you the value in the
inputArray adress(the first element), inputArray[1] gives you the second element and so on... So what does intSwapper do - you go from the first element to the middle and just swap the values in the address of the first <-> last, second <-> last-1 and so on elements. temp variable is needed, so you don't lose the value of inputArray[i] after you assign inputArray[size - 1 - i] to it. It is important to understand this code and if you cannot, google something like "c++ array tutorial". Also you don't need to return pointer, because you have it, when you pass it to intSwapper. intSwapper will just rearrange the values in the memory the pointer points to.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your question "How can I return an array" there are multiple possibilities.

If you're using arrays of which the size is known at compile time, use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)
e.g.

```cpp
#include<array>

std::array<int, 5> MyArrayFactory(){
    std::array<int, 5> arr;
    // do some things to fill arr
    return arr; // RVO prevents copy
}
```

or if you ***really*** want to use a static array, return a reference

```cpp
std::array<int, 5>& GetStaticCoefficients() {
    static std::array<int, 5> coef { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    return coef;
}
```

(note, I'm explicitly specifying the function return type for demonstrative purposes, but you could just `auto` it (or `auto&` in the second example))

If you don't know the size upfront, use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Example:

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

std::vector<int> SquaredCopyOf (std::vector<int> const& in) {
    std::vector<int> out;
    // either reserve and backinserter
    // or resize and iterator
    out.reserve(in.size());
    std::transform(cbegin(in), cend(in), back_inserter(out),
        [](auto el) { return el*el;} );
    return out;
}
```

Note that in C++20 we get more possibilities, with `std::range`, `std::range::view` and `std::span`, but since you're a beginner I'll leave them out.

Then I would like to comment on your use of `delete`... It seems you think that all pointers need to be deleted. That's false. `delete` de-allocates dynamically allocated memory (allocated using `new`). So if you don't allocate memory, you don't have to de-allocate it.

In modern C++ is it almost never required to use `new` and `delete` anymore, since we use abstractions as `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`.