# How to return an array in method decleration using C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I am trying to write C++ code suitable for object oriented programming.

I have two classes, namely, `Student` and `Course`. In the `Student` class, I have `quiz_scores` which is a 1-D array of 4 integers. I need both set and get methods, both are used in natural common way.

In the following, I implement `setQuizScores` method:

```cpp
void Student :: setQuizScores(int* quizscores){
   for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
      quiz_scores[i] = quizscores[i];
   }
```

Where `quizscores` are my private members.

Now, next thing is that I want to return this `quiz_scores` array in the `getQuizScores` for each students of Student class.

However, the problem is that C++ does not allow us to return arrays directly. Instead, I want the structure of my code as following:

```cpp
int Student :: getQuizScores(){
   Do something;
   return the elements of quiz_scores;
}
```

How can I do that efficiently?

I prefer not to use the Standard Template Library (STL), so I need to create my own arrays and access them according to the explanation above.

Comment: *since C++ does not allow us to return arrays directly* -- Use `std:::array<int, 4>`, then all of those issues go away.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I prefer not using STL.  I should create my own arrays in a standard way.

Comment: Then put the array into a `struct`. In opposition to arrays, `struct`s can be returned by value. (Actually, `std::array` does nothing else.)

Comment: A note: Return type `int` and _return the elements of quiz_scores;_ doesn't go well together.

Comment: You really should start learning STL, most of C++ _is_  about STL. Not using STL reduces C++ to "C with classes". Using STL _is_ the standard C++ way.

Comment: The primary choice for arrays where the size is not known before run-time is `std::vector`. ...but this is yet another _standard way_. (Who on earth prohibited to use the _standard way_?)

Comment: @Scheff's Cat, yes but I just try to explain what I want to do in the code.

Comment: @YalçınCenik please show the declaration of your `Student` class.

Comment: @YalçınCenik *I prefer not to use the Standard Template Library (STL)* -- Nothing stops you from creating an Array class, just like you created your other classes (a [struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410943/returning-arrays-from-a-function-in-c/27411483#27411483) that contains an array is one such class).  Then the problem becomes moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as `setQuizScores()` is able to take a pointer to an array, so too can `getQuizScores()` return a pointer to the `quiz_scores` member array, eg:

```cpp
const int* Student::getQuizScores() const {
   // do something...
   return quiz_scores;
}
```

The caller can then access the array elements as needed, eg:

```cpp
Student s;
...
const int *scores = s.getQuizScores();
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
   cout << scores[i] << ' ';
}
```

Alternatively, since the array is fixed size, you can return a reference to the array instead, eg:

```cpp
typedef int scoresArr[4];
scoresArr quiz_scores;

...

const scoresArr& Student::getQuizScores() const {
   // do something...
   return quiz_scores;
}
```

```cpp
Student s;
...
const scoresArr &scores = s.getQuizScores();
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
   cout << scores[i] << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways how you could return an array:

##### Pass in an array to copy to

```cpp
void Student::getQuizScores(int* out) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        out[i] = quiz_scores[i];
}

Student student;
int scores[4];
student.getQuizScores(scores);
// use scores[0], etc...
```

##### return a struct containing the array

```cpp
struct Scores {
    int values[4];
};

Scores Student::getQuizScores() {
    Scores s;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        s.values[i] = quiz_scores[i];
    return s;
}

Student student;
Scores s = student.getQuizScores();
// use s.values[0], etc...
```

##### return a reference to the quiz_scores array inside the class

```cpp
using Scores = int[4];

Scores const& Student::getQuizScores() const {
    return quiz_scores;
}

Student student;
Scores const& scores = student.getQuizScores();
// use scores[0], etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a pointer to the `quiz_scores` array through `getQuizScores` method as shown below:

**Version 1**: Using trailing return type

```
auto getQuizScores() -> int(*)[4]
    {
       //Do something;
       return &quiz_scores;//NOTE THE & INFRONT OF quiz_scores
    }
```

Now you can use this returned pointer to initialize other arrays. One possible example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Student
{
    int quiz_scores[4]= {1,2,3,4};
    //getQuizScores returns a pointer to an array of size 4 with element of type int
    auto getQuizScores() -> int(*)[4]
    {
       //Do something;
       return &quiz_scores;//NOTE THE & INFRONT OF quiz_scores
    }
    void setQuizScores(int* quizscores)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
       {
       quiz_scores[i] = quizscores[i];
       }
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    Student s;
    
    int arr[4];
    
    for(int i = 0; i< 4; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = (*s.getQuizScores())[i];
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Version 2**: Without using trailing return type

```
int (*getQuizScores())[4]
{
   //Do something;
   return &quiz_scores;//NOTE THE & INFRONT OF quiz_scores
}
```

Version 2 is the same as version 1 except that this time the `getQuizScores` method does not uses trialing return type.

There are other possibilities also like returning a reference to the `quiz_scores` array.